# How to show the phone number and email selector dialogs using play-services-* depdendencies?

Tags: java, android, authentication, kotlin, google-play-services

This has been asked a lot however all the solution now seem outdated since the deprecation of `GoogleApiClient`.

I want to show a dialog that lists the phone numbers present on the user's device. And separately, a dialog showing all emails associated with the device.

- Is there a solution not using GoogleApiClient? (which is now deprecated)
- The solution should not involve any scary permissions (I'm not a fan of asking for a permission just for auto-filling)
- What is the typical success rate of the solution? What android versions is it available in? How often do OEMs screw around with it resulting in it not working? (which happened with the GoogleApiClient solution)
- In general, I do not care about firebase, Google sign in, or anything auth related. I just want a popup with phone numbers and another popup with emails so users can select it in one go and then I go and do my own auth. (It seemed like some solutions were pushing for GoogleSignIn which is not even relevant to the problem)

As an example, the generally accepted method for all such questions is the following method:

```
        val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build()

        val intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
            googleApiClient, hintRequest
        )
        startIntentSenderForResult(
            intent.intentSender,
            123, null, 0, 0, 0, null
        )
```

However, this no longer works. A dialog flashes and goes away and I get back Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED (0) result code in onActivityResult. So, either this functionality has been randomly stopped by play services, it is unreliably implemented by OEMs or is there a new non-deprecated method to do this?

Let's stop the confusion here. Are you aware of a reliable way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Aditya, thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately I don't know of a public bug tracker for this, but I'll ask internally and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: That would be amazing @aaronstacy

Comment: Any updates @aaronstacy?

Comment: @Davidsun answer is the only update I've got 

Answer (score 2):

There're a few issues mentioned in the post and I'll address them one by one.

1. Is there a solution not using GoogleApiClient? -> We are working on a new solution but it will be slightly different than what we currently offer. The new solution allows the user to pick a Google account for sign-in. The phone number feature isn't in place yet and I'll talk about it later. The new API will be out by the end of Q1 / early Q2.
2. I agree with you for accounts. However, in order to get a phone number, the app needs to hold a phone number related permission (see Android permission docs for details) or we need to beef up the consent / data source. We're not planning to change it for the current solution. It is true that right now the permissions are mixed, i.e. phone number permission is required if the app is only asking for emails - expect it to be fixed in our new API.
3. The *current* solution is available for all devices. This is also in response to your question below: yes the current implementation might have a flickering issue when there's no data for the user to select. We're going to improve the API so that the app doesn't need to launch the intent if there's no data. For the success rate, if you use the new API, you should be able to measure the success rate within your app since Google API's behavior is less opaque.
4. Google sign-in doesn't provide phone number feature today, and nor does the new API that we're about to publish. However, the team is in consideration to build phone number feature in our new API. Just to be clear: the new phone number feature we're considering, is verified phone number backed by Google account but not phone number autofill. We'd like to hear some feedback from you on this one :)

Comment: Do we have any updates on this?